# We had wood fence installed & one area at a corner, the ground dips downs 3 feet. Can I fill that area with stones?

Tags: fence

[image]

We had wood fence installed & one area at a corner, the ground dips downs 3 feet. Can I fill that area with stones? The area is the right side of photo. I want to level the area with stones. I don’t want to use soil b

Comment: Without seeing a larger area, that looks like a drainage path for water, or might just be a dip in the ground.  Stones can be used, but might slow down/block water drainage enough to be bothersome.

Comment: If you're wanting to make the fence line even across the top which would expose a gap at the ground, stones would be no worse than the wood when it comes to blocking drainage. Adding stones in addition to the fence might reduce flow, but confirm by observing how drainage looks during a heavy rainstorm. From your photo, I'd guess that the drainage goes further downhill to the right.

Comment: How 'bout a photo with the area in question in the center of the view and not blocked by trees or anything else? That would probably help us help you.

Comment: Are you wanting to pile 3 feet of stone (vertically) against the fence? Probably not a survivable idea, from the fence's point of view. Do you want to level the fence, in which case the order of operations seems out of order, as the fence is already built, so it's complex to remove the fence, level the ground, and rebuild the fence - but if that's what you want, it might at least work. But you'd need to rebuild both fences at that corner.

Comment: You would need to install some rot-proof facing on the fence before you pile rock against it.